# How to filter posts by Newest, Oldest, A-Z, and Z-A in one drop-down in Wordpress on index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am able to filter by desc and asc. But how do I also filter from A-Z and Z-A all within the same select option?

I've been able to do:

- ?order=desc
- ?order=asc

I want to also be able to do:

- ?order=desc&orderby=title
- ?order=asc&orderby=title

I can do either, but I am unable to get it to do both.

```
<select id="video-filter" name="order">
 <option class="filter-date" value="desc">Newest</option>
 <option class="filter-date" value="asc">Oldest</option>
 <option class="filter-alpha" value="asc">A-Z</option>
 <option class="filter-alpha" value="desc">Z-A</option>
 <input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="orderby" value="title">
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have any PHP code on how it currently handles the sorting?

Comment: You need more than one select, or you'll have to combine the select options...

Comment: Okay so I think I figured it out. Initially if the hidden input is value="" - how do I get it to add "title" thru JQuery?